# Angular2 Material dist too big

Tags: c#, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a C# based website. (www.recognitiongame.com)

First, I want to use an Angular2 Material Menu component. I have created this in an Angular project and put to my site with ng build. It's working.
(The ng-build has created a dist folder, I put the js files to my site and linked to them)

The problem is that the .js files are too big (~7-8MB).

How can I set to put (compile?) only the menu component from Angular2/material, not the all @angular/material.

Thanks, 
   Imre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to update your Material 2 version to [2.0.0-beta.10](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-d%C3%A9coupage-panjandrum-2017-08-29). Then, instead of importing `MaterialModule`, import separate component modules. Importing separate modules helps in tree-shaking and any unused module is dropped from the final build output.

In you case, you need to import only `MdMenuModule`.

```
import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular/material';

.....
imports: [ MdMenuModule ]
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply, I will probe in afternoon. How can I update to that version?

Comment: I have changed the app.module.ts file with your instructions, but still the big sizes for example: vendor.bundle.js still ~3.9MB, vendor.bundle.js.map still 4.6MB.

Comment: You dont need js.map files, vendor.bundle.js is fine with that size

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I'm new in Angular, but still learning... ;-)

Comment: @Imre, Have you tried compiling your project with `ng build -prod --build-optimizer` (suposing you set up angular-cli)?

Comment: Yes, I have read a lot about this and I build the project like you said. The result reduced ~700kB.